# Does Firebase's Firestore work better with an express API?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, api, express, google-cloud-firestore

I followed some Firestore tutorials and I didn't need to build an API, instead, Firestore connected with the front end and offered features similar to an API. Is this the optimal way to use Firestore? Should I be building an API on top of my front end app to connect to Firestore?

I'm new to using Firestore and NoSQL but I want to quickly build an MVP that's scalable. I'm used to building a python (Flask) API and a PostgreSQL DB, but I want to do something simpler and quicker. Any insight into how Firestore works will help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is kinda of vague; when you say *I didn't need to build an API*, what does that mean? Firestore is a NoSQL database with a SDK (software developer kit) and the entire package is part of the API (application programming interface). You generally work within the API to create apps (applications/programs), not build one (unless you are an API developer). Can you clarify your question? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The community is not about giving an opinion about architecture, if you have a problem implementing some firestore then that would be a valid question, otherwise there is not much to answer with a 'correct' answer.

Comment: Yeah I know this was a vague question about architecture and firebase's SDK, however, that's why I couldn't find an answer for it and I wasn't sure where/what exactly to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to know if you should create a back end API to request/pass data between your front end and Firestore.

You do not need your own custom API to connect with Firestore. Googles SDK connects directly from your front-end to your Firestore. Here is their [quick start guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart).

To make this secure, you will need to set good security rules as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: Thank you I figured this was the case but I wasn't sure if that was optimal. Appreciate it